# Trouble trying to update a scope variable using Firebase facebook connect and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frameworks, firebase

here's the thing...

I'm using AngularJS, and trying to use firebird's facebook connect to try a few things.

Everything is almost fine, it connects to my facebook, and returns the information of my account, but here is the thing, as i'm using angular, i'll use the ng-show and ng-hide to show and hide the connect button right?

so i have a structure like that:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="logedUser">
        <a href="" ng-click="loginFacebook()">Login with Facebook</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="checkAuth()">check</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="logedUser">
        <a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The logedUser verifies if the user is loged or not, so its true or false, making one div to be showing, and the other to be hiding.

the problem is when i try to update this variable thought my angular controller, here is the code:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.loginFacebook = function() {
    auth.login('facebook', {
        rememberMe: true,
        scope: 'email,user_likes'
    });
};

$scope.logout = function() {
    auth.logout();
};

$scope.checkAuth = function() {
    console.log($scope);
};

var loginRef = new Firebase('https://angulartodolist.firebaseIO.com/');

var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(loginRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);

        $scope.logedUser = false;
    } else if (user) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        console.log(user);

        $scope.logedUser = true;
    } else {
        // user is logged out
        $scope.logedUser = false;
    }
}); });
```

so what is happening, when i click on login, it calls the loginFacebook() function, it authenticates, and then returns my users info, after that, i change the logedUser variable to true, using $scope.logedUser = true;

But in my front-end its not changing the divs, so i created a function called checkAuth(), just to access the controller, and making a simple console.log, after i execute that function, it changes the divs, making the login div to disappear, and the logout div to appear...

shouldnt it happens automaticaly just by setting the variables in the Firebase's callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
$scope.$apply()
```

in FirebaseSimpleLogin callback function :)

Usually, every callback outside "angular's world" need this to refresh its scope.